# Error in xml serialization

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error when I try to serialize `List<SLItem>`:

> There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

```
[Serializable]
public class SLItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ActorName { get; set; }  
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> VerLookup { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

[Instead of the Dictionary use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net) a list of:

```
[Serializable]
public struct KeyValuePair<K,V>
{
  public K Key {get;set;}
  public V Value {get;set;}
}
```

So your Dictionary becomes:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>
```

XmlSerializer cannot serialize classes that have read-only properties. Dictionaries contain KeyValuePair<>'s which are implemented with read-only key and value properties.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can serialize the Dictionary. This post may help: [There was an error reflecting type - XML Serialization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407200/there-was-an-error-reflecting-type-xml-serialization-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a child class which implements IXmlSerializable.
Some time ago I've created it and serialization to XML works.
Here is the code!

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml;


[XmlRoot("dictionary")]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }


    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));
        bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();
        if (wasEmpty)
            return;

        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");
            reader.ReadStartElement("key");
            TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.ReadStartElement("value");
            TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();
            this.Add(key, value);
            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");
            writer.WriteStartElement("key");
            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("value");
            TValue value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```